# Phaser state manager can't find certain states?

Tags: javascript, state, phaser-framework

My index.html file seems to include all of the necessary JS files, and then defines their state. This is what I've seen people do online and it works fine for them.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src = "phaser.js"></script>
    <script src = "Boot.js"></script>
    <script src = "Preload.js"></script>
    <script src = "MainMenu.js>"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){

            var game = new Phaser.Game(800,600,Phaser.AUTO,'');

            game.state.add('Boot',Game.Boot);
            game.state.add('Preload',Game.Preload);
            game.state.add('MainMenu',Game.MainMenu);

            game.state.start('Boot');

        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that while this code successfully changes state from Boot.js to Preload.js, it claims that there is "No state found with the key: MainMenu". I'm super confused, and I'm using Phaser version 2.6.1

For the sake of your weary eyes, I've included the Boot.js file, the Preload.js and the MainMenu.js file in one concatenated Pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/sJYTsCdY .

Sorry if I've made any etiquette mistakes, this is my first time posting to StackOverflow. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: I've tried your Pastebin file and it works fine. It gives errors due to resources not found, but there is no error in starting the MainMenu state. Maybe it's due to case sensitive filenames and capital letters in the file name? In Chrome you can press `ctrl+shift+J` to see the console log, does it give any other error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Game.MainMenu` to `Game.MainMenu.prototype` at row 76 in the pastebin.

What I supposе is happening is Phaser tries to add `MainMenu` as a new state and when it tries to instantiate it, it fails because there is no function to act as constructor (that it needs when using `new` and that's what Phaser uses internally when adding a state). You define `Game.MainMenu = function() { }` which acts as a constructor at first, but then you override it (you assign something else to the same `Game.MainMenu`) and it happens that Phaser can no longer create an instance of MainMenu.

Comment: @iijb That's what I implied.